# test MediaLibraryService with Hilt

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-hilt, android-media3

I'm working on lots of tests.   We are using MediaLibraryService with Hilt.   It's a big part of the app.  We don't have any tests for that yet.  I googled around for how to test the MediaLibraryService and didn't find much.  Then I went to media3 github, and I see they have lots of tests there, but I don't see anything for that with Hilt.

Since the service inject dependencies to fields (opposed to inject via the constructor), I assume I'd have to create some test modules (possibly quite a few). Hilt was very handy to testing other parts like viewModels and repositories.  Might be a pain here.

I'd like start with some simple tests that would confirm custom commands are working.   So probably have mock player, and see the commands get the mock player.  And making sure the recent item is saved.  I think once I have everything setup to test the service with hilt for those simple tests, I can go to town.

When moving to media3, we had some bugs with them.  I believe they are working now, but we try very hard to create tests for any bug (really for any change to the code for any reason).

If anyone can point me towards examples for testing MediaLibraryService with Hilt or any other information that would help, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Well, an obvious start: Do all the things need for any test that uses Hilt. `@HiltAndroidTest
class ServiceTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule: HiltAndroidRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)


    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }
}`
 and add HiltTestRunner and set up it in gradle.   We used the pattern of having serviceConnection, I can us the serviceConnection in the tests, and get the service to start and get a player.